# ON Semi MOSFET datasheet - how can this be consistent? (it must be me)

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

The [ON Semiconductor datasheet for the 2N7000G](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/2N7000-D-33553.pdf) "Small Signal MOSFET 200 mAmps" gives information that I can't reconcile.
(By way of background I am teaching myself about MOSFETs and I am going through the process of verifying the published data by conducting practical experiments on the bench).
[image: Page 1 of the datasheet]
The first page states that this is a small signal MOSFET with a maximum power dissipation of 350mW.
The third page, on figure 1, gives characteristic curves plotting ID against VDS for a several values of VGS in the usual way.
[image: Page 3 of the datasheet]
If we look at a typical point in the middle of the figure, VDS = 5 volts and VGS = 7 volts gives ID = 0.8 Amps.
Multiplying VDS x ID gives 4 Watts dissipated in the device which is over 10 times the maximum permitted.
Clearly I have misunderstood something here. The manufacturer would not give data for an operating point that would result in magic smoke every time. So where am I going wrong please?

Comment: In some applications, you might have 4 watts dissipation for a very brief moment. There might be a "safe operating area" chart showing different time durations

Comment: 200 mA isn't the maximum physically possible, it's the maximum you can do continuously without damage. The same goes for the power rating; maximum continuous without damage. (this gets Complicated with power MOSFETs that tend to give their current ratings under the assumption of perfect heatsinking, but for a 2N7000 it works like you'd expect.)

Comment: Why are you ignoring the Maximum Ratings on page 1?  They clearly state a maximum \$I_D\$ = 200mA continuous and = 500mA pulsed.

Comment: The secret to understanding datasheets is not to take each spec in isolation. Recently I was reviewing a circuit where I suspected the SOA parameters were being violated. The mosfet was well within its voltage and current ratings but the SOA specs tell another part of the story. Simulations showed we were on the bleeding edge so steps were taken to mitigate the problem. HiK ceramic capacitors are another tricky component where you need to review the datasheet carefully. Just because the datasheet says 10uF 16V doesn’t mean you are going to actually get your 10uF.You might be lucky to get 2uF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic answer is: **more  is permitted briefly**, with "briefly" defined in other information not in the datasheet you copied from.

Later versions of the datasheet show the safe operating area, ie the bounding times for various powers (at  V<sub>GS</sub>=10 V).  You'll see 0.1 A at 2 V<sub>DS</sub> = 2V is permitted indefinitely.

From https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/nds7002a-d.pdf
[image]